# COLMAP mapper is failing to do its job

Tags: colmap

I am trying to use COLMAP to do a sparse reconstruction

When I try to use the mapper with

```
#!/bin/bash
DATASET_PATH=$1

colmap mapper \
    --database_path $DATASET_PATH/database.db \
    --image_path $DATASET_PATH/images \
    --output_path $DATASET_PATH/sparse \
    --Mapper.ba_refine_focal_length 0 \
    --Mapper.ba_refine_principal_point  0 \
    --Mapper.ba_refine_extra_params  0 \
    --Mapper.init_max_forward_motion 1.0 \
    --Mapper.init_min_tri_angle 2.0
```

I get a long output that seems it is working and among this multiple instances of

I0213 03:50:28.688235   194 incremental_mapper.cc:495] => Image sees 570 / 4847 points
I0213 03:50:28.688555   194 incremental_mapper.cc:535] => Could not register, trying another image.
I0213 03:50:28.688558   194 misc.cc:198]

In the end after visualizing the results the sparse reconstruction fails completely
What can be the issue? I dont know what the above message could mean